# How can null reference result in SEH exception with code 0xc0000005?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, nullreferenceexception, googletest

I'm writing some test code using the [Google C++ Test Framework](https://github.com/google/googletest) and forgot to initialize a certain object `myObj`. This results in the following error.

```
unknown file: error: SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body
```

Stepping through the corresponding code it appears that a method call of the form

```
myObj->method()
```

is executed, while myObj is not initialized, i.e. its value is `0x00000000`. Then somewhere deep in a third party library this error is thrown.

How can this even happen? Why doesn't it throw a null reference exception as soon as the method is called?

Comment: If `method` doesn't use any members of the class, it may just not notice that its being called on a `nullptr`. However, if it hands out a reference to a member to someone, that someone may be the first one to actually try to reach through that nullptr.

Comment: Calling a method from a NULL pointer is undefined behavior. So everything can happen, including the method is executed.

Comment: C++ is not java. In Java using a NULL object is guaranteed to throw the relevant exception. In C++ it is just undefined behaviour meaning that the compiler if free to test for the null pointer and throw an exception or not test anything and try to execute code from a bad location ending in SIGSEGV or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was rightfully pointed out in comments, calling a method from the uninitialized class pointer is an undefined behavior, so anything could happen, depending on the compiler implementation. However, it is easy to predict why in your case execution was semi-successful. The only difference between class (`__thiscall`) members and ordinal functions, is that they receive additional hidden argument, containing a pointer to the class instance (`this`). Microsoft C++ compiler passes `this` argument through `ecx/rcx` register, other compilers may use a different approach. However if your class method is not trying to dereference invalid `this` pointer, no exception will be thrown, and, depending on the method logic, your program could even continue execution without error. Things would be much different, if you try to call a virtual method. In this case, your program would try to calculate correct method address, using class `vtable`, dereference an invalid pointer and fail with access violation even if method itself is not using `this` pointer.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to force this latter behaviour you describe?

Comment: Well, you could declare all your class members as virtual functions. You should understand, that this will have small negative impact on the memory consumption (class instances would be bigger) and performance. However, you could use preprocessor definitions to force this behavior only in debug code.

Comment: The suggested method (make everything `virtual`) does not work reliably. MSVC++ is known to _devirtualize_ calls - treat calls of `virtual` methods as normal calls when it can statically deduce the runtime type.